# jQuery scrolling end and last child element selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, scroll, mousewheel

I used the jQuery mousewheel plugin to help me determine if the user has scrolled up or down. If the user scrolls up, I would like the last child of a parent element to be displayed as none. This works, but only once.  The other elements in the parent fail to go to `display:none`.

One option I thought of was to use the `.empty()` but when I use that none of the elements disappear.

I created a working example and I will below post the code that I think is causing the trouble. http://jsbin.com/orocat/1/edit

Javascript code only:

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {

if (delta > 0) {  
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {

    //here is the code that is causing trouble. I realize that it is
    //only selecting the last child but if I used .empty() nothing happens?
    $('.body div:last-child').css('display','none');

}, 80));} 

    else {  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {

    //have div elements display themselves again. need to work on this
    }, 80));}

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your following line:

```
$('.body div:last-child').css('display','none');
```

for this one:

```
$('.body div:visible').eq(-1).css('display','none');
```

because you were selecting the same div again and again, because making it hidden it's not like removing it, so your selector kept selecting it.

Comment: Thanks. Never knew about `.eq()`.

Answer (score 2):

You keep setting the last `DIV` to `display:none`;

Whenever you use this selector `$('.body div:last-child').css('display','none');` you are selecting the same DIV each time.  It seems like you want to select the next DIV up each time maybe?  Try using `div:visible` as well.